# How to automate yFiles for HTML based Graph

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, yfiles

Is there any automation tool available to automate yfiles for HTML based graph?
Or is there a way to use selenium for automating it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium for this task. What's important to consider is that yFiles uses state machines internally for the processing of the events and therefor the events should be simulated like they would happen in the real world.

This means that instead of just dispatching `click` events, you would need to simulate the correct series of events that lead to a click: `mousemove`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click` and for a drag there should be one or more `mousemove`s, `mousedown`, one or more `mousemove`s, and a `mouseup`.

Sadly Selenium does not do this automatically for you, but writing a couple of helper functions that will perform a proper click or drag is a one-time setup. You can then use `dispatchEvent` to dispatch synthetic events to the main component and write high-level tests that will perform a series of user interactions.